# Liferay Asset - How to update liferay asset without changing create date?

Tags: java, liferay

I use the com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil to update existing entry or to create new entry if it does not exist. However I don't want to change the createdDate, so I don't want to pass those two parameters. This overriden function exists, however it is deprecated. Which function should I use instead? The Java documentation contains no comments.

Example:
This function accepts createdDate and updatedDate parameters:

```
        AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(userId, // userId
                groupId,// groupId
                new Date(),// create date
                new Date(),// modifiedDate
                PeriodicalIssueDto.class.getName(),// class name
                dto.getId(), // class PK
                "" + dto.getId(), // class uuid
                0L, // classTypeId
                null,// categoryIds
                null,// tagNames
                true,// visible
                new Date(),// startDate
                null,// endDate
                null, // expirationDate
                "text",// mimeType
                dto.getTitle(),// title
                null,// description
                null,// summary
                null, // url
                null,// layoutUuid
                0, // height
                0,// width
                0, // priority
                false// sync
                );
```

But the similar function without createDate and modifiedDate is deprecated:

```
        AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(
                userId, // userId
                groupId,// groupId
                PeriodicalIssueDto.class.getName(),// class name
                dto.getId(), // class PK
                "" + dto.getId(), // class uuid
                0L, // classTypeId
                null,// categoryIds
                null,// tagNames
                true,// visible
                new Date(),// startDate
                null,// endDate
                null, // expirationDate
                "text",// mimeType
                dto.getTitle(),// title
                null,// description
                null,// summary
                null, // url
                null,// layoutUuid
                0, // height
                0,// width
                0, // priority
                false// sync
                );
```

How can I create or update new entry without handling the createDate and modifiedDate myslef?

Answer (score 0):

After little bit of decompilation I found the answer.

The version with createDate and modifiedDate should be used.

createDate is considered for new Entry only. If null is passed, then new Date() is created automatically

modifiedDate is set according to the input parameter. If null is passed, then new Date() is used automatically.